# Testable Kotlin objects that uses a dispatcher in init block?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, robolectric

I have a class that looks like this:

```kotlin
object SomeRepository {

    private val logger = Logger(this)

    private val flow: MutableStateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // some code
        }
    }

    fun list() = flow.value

    fun observe(): StateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = flow

}
```

It is [recommended to inject dispatchers in tests](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#injecting-test-dispatchers).

Also, there is a risk to get [weird problems](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/7055) such as `AppNotIdleException` if not following this practice.

One option would be to make these into variables and add setters, but not very nice. Also it creates a race condition (init-block vs setters):

```kotlin
object SomeRepository {

    private val logger = Logger(this)

    private val flow: MutableStateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())

    private var coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope
    private var dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    init {
        dispatcher.launch(coroutineScope) {
            // some code
        }
    }

    fun list() = flow.value

    fun observe(): StateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = flow

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setDispatcher(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setCoroutineScope(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
        this.coroutineScope = coroutineScope
    }

}
```

Version that avoids the race condition (test needs to explicitly invoke `init()`):

```kotlin
object SomeRepository {

    private val logger = Logger(this)

    private val flow: MutableStateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())

    private var coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope
    private var dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    init {
        // var isInTesting = Build.FINGERPRINT == "robolectric"
        if (!isInTesting) {
            init()
        }
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun init() {
        dispatcher.launch(coroutineScope) {
            // some code
        }
    }

    fun list() = flow.value

    fun observe(): StateFlow<List<SomeClass>> = flow

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setDispatcher(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setCoroutineScope(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
        this.coroutineScope = coroutineScope
    }

}
```

How can I inject a coroutine scope and dispatcher to my tests and avoid variables?

Comment: What is the purpose of the code that is run in the `init` block? Also, why is this an `object` and not a regular class, which you could create instances of (and with different dispatchers or scopes)?

Comment: The init block basically retrieves data from a few sources and combine them into entities that are exposed through the repository pattern

Comment: So does it make sense for someone to be able to use the repository when this work is not finished? (I'm questioning the `launch` here). And if the coroutine hangs for some reason, does it make sense for it to leak for the lifetime of the application? (I'm questioning the `GlobalScope` here)

Comment: Question 1: It would be OK for this repository to return an empty list until this work is completed. Do you suggest `runBlocking {}` instead or instantiating `flow` inside the init block?
Question 2: The options are quite limited given that it is a singleton object. Would it make any difference to instantiate a new CoroutineScope instead?

Comment: The thing is, using an `object` is also questionable. Singletons make testing complicated, hence why you ended up asking this question I presume. If you *instantiated* this class instead, then you could inject scopes or dispatchers into it without the need for setters and make testing easy. But yeah, if you keep a singleton here, I guess it wouldn't bring much to create your own scope anyway, since you would never cancel it.